# Issue with Pybamm Tutorial

Tags: python, battery

I am going through the PYbamm tutorial of setting parametres from the official site.

```
parameter_values["Current function [A]"] = 10
parameter_values["Open-circuit voltage at 100% SOC [V]"]=3.4
parameter_values["Open-circuit voltage at 0% SOC [V]"]=3.0
```

when i run this part of the code i get an error whether it be locally or using the google colab

```
'Open-circuit voltage at 100% SOC [V]' not found. Best matches are ['SEI open-circuit potential [V]', 'Outer SEI open-circuit potential [V]', 'Upper voltage cut-off [V]']"
```

When i check the parameter list provided on the site this exists however when i run the cod on either platform these parameters are not there

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar issue.
Name of these parameters are changed in PyBaMm version 23.5. These parameter names work fine with an older version.

You may try the following in PyBaMm 23.5:

```
 parameter_values["Current function [A]"] = 10 
 parameter_values['Lower voltage cut-off [V]']= 3.0
 parameter_values['Upper voltage cut-off [V]']=3.4
```